# Certificates of origin for electricity that was subsidised by Germany's EEG (Renewable Energy Law)

Tags: energy-economics, law, subsidies, policy

In Germany there is the [EEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Renewable_Energy_Sources_Act) (Erneuerbare Energien Gesetz - Renewable Energy Law).

The rough outline of the law is as follows: If I run a solar installation and feed electricity into the grid, I get a fixed amount of money per kWh as compensation (you may heard about FET - Feed in Tarifs). The Umweltbundesamt (Ministry of the environment [german acronym is UBA]) becomes the owner of the electricity and sells it at the wholesale market. If there is a difference between the cost for subsidy and the revenue gained from the sales, the cost is paid from the national budget. In the past this was partly shouldered by energy consumers via an additional tax on electricity but this was recently abolished.

However, this ruling only holds true for small installations. When you get over a certain size you are forced to sell your electricity yourself on the wholesale market (for example at the European Energy Exchange [EEX]) or via over the counter trades with energy companies. However, you can get a certificate of origin for your green energy from the UBA.You can separately trade those certificates. And electricity retailers that buy those certificates can claim the energy they sell to be from renewables. This can be advantageous in marketing because green energy contracts are gaining popularity in Germany.

Now I have a question: If big installations get certificates of origin, then the same should be possible for small installations. However, the owner of that electricity is the UBA because they paid for it with the EEG subsidy. So, is the UBA also selling certificates of origin?

Background of my question is that energy retailers in Germany are very transparent with the origin of their energy. I wonder whether they can claim the energy they buy from the UBA to be renewable or not.